# Ability to filter by career stage on academia stackexchange

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags

Coming to Academia StackExchange from StackOverflow, I am a bit confused about being the frequent lack of tags allowing to best sort the questions for relevance to me. Whereas on StackOverflow almost every question is citing a programming language and a framework - two factors critical for relevance and filtering, only a minority of Academia StackExchange questions use tags indicating the career stage (undergrad, PhD, Post-Doc, faculty) making filtering questions hard to impossible.

Is there a way of working around it, for instance with search option? If not, are there plans of modifying a behavior? Or are there usage patterns allowing to work around it?

Comment: Given the variability of the academic environment around the world, I'm not sure whether this kind of filtering would be useful: in Italy or in the US, C++ is C++, but a postdoc position can be quite different.

Comment: A second level of tags (country) was actually my follow-up suggestion/request. French/German systems are particularly opaques for those who haven't done their PhDs / post-docs in those countries. In the same way the PhDs in the US (6-8 years) have a very different nature than the PhDs in Europe (3-4) or undergrad research experience in countries with undergrad advisors (US; UK) is very different from countries where this is not the case (France, ...). Both of these tags are critical for judging the context of the question.

Answer (score 2):

There is a limit of five tags allowed per question.

However, there are tags for a number of different systems, including in particular tags for France and Germany. So it is possible to propose edits to tags if it's necessary. It's also more likely that if you're looking for specific questions to find it via the search bar, in case someone hasn't tagged the question the way you'd like it to be done.

Many of the questions are not tagged by career stage because the stage is identified in the topic of the question (and thus can be searched for), or because the question might be relevant across multiple types (and therefore is not helpful).

Comment: And many times we have difficulties in convincing people at adding the proper country tag.